# Insert Automatically datetime in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am new in Yii Framework.I want to insert date in database when new record entered.here is my model rules

```
public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('user_id, question, creation_Datetime, creator_id', 'required'),
            array('user_id, creator_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, user_id, question, creation_Datetime, creator_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
```

Please Help

Comment: Take a look at the [timestamp behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [refrence](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/10/how-to-automate-timestamps-in-activerecord-models/)

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if ($this->isNewRecord)
        $this->created = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
    else
        $this->modified = new CDbExpression('NOW()');

    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

or

```
/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('title','length','max'=>255),
        array('title, created, modified', 'required'),
        array('modified','default',
              'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
              'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'update'),
        array('created,modified','default',
              'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
              'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'insert')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Question comments @chris pointed it to Yii 2 but by seeing the array format it clear that you're using either Yii 1.0 or Yii 1.1

So here I write two solutions.

**Yii 1.1**

```
public function behaviors(){
   return array(
      'CTimestampbehavior' => array(
         'class' => 'zii.behaviors.CTimestampbehavior',
         'createAttribute' => 'creation_Datetime',
      )
   );
}
```

**Yii 1.0**

Since yii 1.0 don't have `CTimestampbehavior` class. You can use this way in your model:

```
public function beforeSave() {
  if($this->isNewRecord) {
    $this->creation_Datetime = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL you can use `now()`, to enter the current date.

Comment: While you are correct, your answer does not directly answer the question asked, which is how to do it in Yii automatically.